Adding fontface in css with webpack
I try to use my font I downloaded but I can't use it in css although webpack is adding this to dist directory
{
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  src: url("./fonts/roboto.woff2");
}

location of the font is src/fonts/roboto.woff2
I tried to changing font localization but it didn't work

Roboto is a google font, why not use that way?

well,I thought it's a better practise to store fonts locally

No it is not. Embedding google fonts directly is the best way to go
